# "Premature end of file" error when Java read and writes XML data files

Tags: java, xml, servlets

I have been using JDOM library to read and write XML files through Java Servlets.

Problem is that when I send many requests using AJAX to my servlets which read and write data in XML files, many times it fails displaying error: Premature end of file. How can I synchronize all these read/writes to files or is there any other way to prevent these problem? Let me know if more details are required.

Will use of threads do any good in this situation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two possible solutions are:

- Write your files to thename.xml.part and then once done/closed to a rename to thename.xml, which makes the write closer to being atomic -- the reader can't read it until it's surely done so long as it is looking for ".xml" files only.
- or, use a Database, atomicity is what they do.

Comment: will you please elaborate the answer ?, i am getting the same error but unable to understand your answer.

Comment: @Ry4an flawless solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced such type of problem but exactly not the same. I am sharing my experience about this error. Please, sorry for any inconvenience.

**I have faced the following problem**

1. I have to form a xml file with dynamic variable data. And post that xml to a URL by PostMethod in java.
2. Normally It works. But when dynamic variable data is null. Then it shows the  “Premature end of file".

**Solution:**

1. Just checking the variable is null or not. And it works for me.

Comment: Just FYI "exactly not the same" isn't quite what you mean, I think.  Should be "not exactly the same".  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding all the write requests to a **Process Queue** and then build/append XML by those elements of Queue.

Answer (score -2):

I have also faced this problem. My experience is...

1. Clean Project
2. Rebuild Project

then it will run successfully....