# Error while parsing xml in java

Tags: java, xml

Im trying to parse the XML returned by the Google Geo code API ,but im getting the following error while parsing..

```
 [Fatal Error] :1:1: Premature end of file.
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at test2.main(test2.java:55)
```

amd my code is like this.. im sure that im getting the response xml correctly..

```
        URL u = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=12.983333,77.583333&sensor=false");  
        URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
        uc.setDoOutput(true);

        StringBuffer sbuf=new StringBuffer();

        inxml=uc.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(inxml));

        String res;
        //System.out.println(" Response from Google Maps "+res);
        while ((res = in.readLine()) != null){
               sbuf.append(res).append("\n");
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(" Total Data received  "+sbuf);

        //XML PARSE Starts Here........

        DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(inxml);

     // normalize text representation
        doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize();

       // System.out.println("Root element of the doc is "+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

please suggest mw some help on this..

Thank u.

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708327/premature-end-of-file-error-when-java-read-and-writes-xml-data-files)

Comment: hi John thanks for the reply. the link u suggested is more regarding the synchronization issue,if im not wrong. but i didnt got much help from that..

Comment: @user593424: I guess, it might be lack of closing XML tag(s).

Comment: hi John , Thanks for the help..MeBigFatGuy solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your debugging code is the problem. You read the document to show the xml here

```
while ((res = in.readLine()) != null){
           sbuf.append(res).append("\n");
    }
```

which advances the stream past all the data, then you try to read it again with the parser.

If you remove the debug code it should work.

Comment: hi ,MeBigFatGuy yes u r right that was the mistake i made thank u very much for solving..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to parse from your buffer

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(sbuf.toString())));
```

instead of the inputstream.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I parse Google Maps API :

......

```
        String input = URLEncoder.encode(input, "UTF-8");
        String addressToConnect = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input="+input+"&types=geocode&language=fr&sensor=true&key="+APIKey;

        //Partie connexion
        URL url = new URL(addressToConnect);
        HttpURLConnection connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connexion.connect();
        InputSource geocoderResultInputSource;
        geocoderResultInputSource = new InputSource(connexion.getInputStream());

        //Partie XML/XPATH
        Document geocoderResultDocument = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(geocoderResultInputSource);
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        //On s'assure que la requete envoyée à l'API à bien renvoyée un STATUS = OK cf. Google API
        NodeList nodeListCodeResult = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//status", geocoderResultDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

.....

You can have a full example [Here](http://code.google.com/p/geocoder-library/source/browse/) . I've started to developped this library with some methods that use this mechanism.

Tell me if it's help :)