# How to insert multiple/different hidden fields into XML?

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays, jsp, hidden

I need to insert multiple hidden fields(data) into the XML. Currently, I can only insert one data at one time. Let's say that I have a few 'tiles'(which contains multiple coordinates) to insert into the XML. So, far, I can only insert one 'tile'(data) into the XML at one time.

```
<<==Javascript code==>>    

function moveIt(){ 

if (!moveEnabled||!MovableItem) return;

// display info during testing

X = MovableItem.offsetLeft;

Y = MovableItem.offsetTop;

W = MovableItem.offsetWidth;

H = MovableItem.offsetHeight;

document.getElementById('X').value = X;     
    document.getElementById('Y').value = Y;
    document.getElementById('W').value = W;
    document.getElementById('H').value = H;  

    document.form1.elements['X'].value;
    document.form1.elements['Y'].value;
    document.form1.elements['W'].value;
    document.form1.elements['H'].value;

    }

 <<==JSP codes==>>

 <form name='form1' action='UpdateXML.jsp' method='post'>

 <input type='hidden' name=source value="<%=src%>" />
 <input type='hidden' id="X" name="X" value="<%=X%>"/>
 <input type='hidden' id="Y" name="Y" value="<%=Y%>"/>
 <input type='hidden' id="W" name="W" value="<%=W%>"/>
 <input type='hidden' id="H" name="H" value="<%=H%>"/> 

 <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='editcompany.jsp'">Back!</button>
 <button type="submit">Insert Into XML!</button>
 </form>

 <<==XML==>>

<%
try {

String X        = request.getParameter("X");
    String Y        = request.getParameter("Y");
    String W        = request.getParameter("W");
    String H        = request.getParameter("H");

    pw.println ( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"  );
    pw.println ( "<TemplateEditor>");
    pw.println ( "\t<Logo>");
    pw.print ( "\t\t<X_Coord>"); pw.print (X); pw.println ( "</X_Coord>");
    pw.print ( "\t\t<Y_Coord>"); pw.print (Y); pw.println ( "</Y_Coord>");
    pw.print ( "\t\t<Width>");   pw.print (W); pw.println ( "</Width>");
    pw.print ( "\t\t<Height>");  pw.print (H); pw.println ( "</Height>");
    pw.println ( "\t</Logo>");
    pw.println ( "</TemplateEditor>");

    pw.flush(); 
    pw.close();
    br.close();
    fw.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {}
%>
```

Hope there's some kind soul out there who can help me out! I really really need help. Thanks a lot

Edit:

function $(v){return document.getElementById(v)}

function startMove(e){

```
if (!MovableItem){return;}

canvas=isIE ? "BODY" : "HTML";

    activeItem=isIE ? event.srcElement : e.target;  

    offsetx=isIE ? event.clientX : e.clientX;

    offsety=isIE ? event.clientY : e.clientY;

    lastX=parseInt(MovableItem.style.left);

    lastY=parseInt(MovableItem.style.top);

    lastW=parseInt(MovableItem.style.width);

    lastH=parseInt(MovableItem.style.height);

if (offsetx+scrollAmt[0]>=(MovableItem.parentNode.offsetLeft+parseInt(MovableItem.style.left)+(MovableItem.offsetWidth*.98))|| offsety+scrollAmt[1]>=(MovableItem.parentNode.offsetTop+parseInt(MovableItem.style.top)+(MovableItem.offsetHeight*.98)) ){edge=true; MovableItem.style.cursor="se-resize"} else{edge=false;MovableItem.style.cursor="move"}

moveEnabled=true;

document.onmousemove=moveIt;
```

}

Does this help? Thanks

Comment: So your current code works for one MovableItem, you want to improve it to handle N MovableItems, right? Is N a fixed number, or you don't know it in advance?

Comment: Yes, MovableItem works. And yes, I want it to be able to handle N MovableItems. N is not a fixed number. It depends on how many the user wants to generate. Is there any way to solve this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some hints and suggestions for handling N MovableItems (code is based on your current logic.

**NOTE: it doesn't follow all JavaScript/JSP best practices (that I know of), it's for demo purpose only.**

1.You can use just one hidden input field to save all MovableItems information (instead of creating 4xN hidden fields), because it's easier to handle this way

```
<input type='hidden' id="movableItems" name="movableItems" value="<%=value%>"/>
```

2.update moveIt() function to support N items.
(Assume you have an array called MovableItems, which contains information of all items)

```
function moveIt() {
    if (!moveEnabled || !MovableItems || MovableItems.length === 0) return;
    var value = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < MovableItems.length; i += 1) {
        if (i > 0) {
            value += '|';
        }
        value = [value, MovableItems[i].offsetLeft, ',',
                MovableItems[i].offsetTop, ',',
                MovableItems[i].offsetWidth, ',',
                MovableItems[i].offsetHeight].join('');
    }

    //the hidden field's value would be something like 10,20,50,50|5,5,30,20|1,2,60,20
    document.getElementById('movableItems').value = value;
}
```

---

In UpdateXML.jsp

```
try {
    pw.println ( "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"  );
    pw.println ( "<TemplateEditor>");

    String value = request.getParameter("movableItems");
    String[] items = value.split("\\|");
    int size = items.length;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        String[] coords = items[i].split(",");
        pw.println ( "\t<Logo>");
        pw.print ( "\t\t<X_Coord>"); pw.print(coords[0]); pw.println ( "</X_Coord>");
        pw.print ( "\t\t<Y_Coord>"); pw.print(coords[1]); pw.println ( "</Y_Coord>");
        pw.print ( "\t\t<Width>");   pw.print(coords[2]); pw.println ( "</Width>");
        pw.print ( "\t\t<Height>");  pw.print(coords[3]); pw.println ( "</Height>");
        pw.println ( "\t</Logo>");
    }
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

I'm sure there can be many other ways to do this. I hope this would give you some ideas.

---

Edit:

Here's a possible way to create/update/delete MovableItems array:

```
var MovableItems = []; //create an empty array
```

A possible implementation for handling create/update/delete a MovableItem

Note: it assume you assign each MovableItem a unique id when it's generated in the UI

```
function getItem(items, id) { //helper function for getting item from array by id
    for (var i = items.length; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        if (items[i].id === id) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

function updateMovable(MovableItem) {
    var index = getItem(MovableItems, MovableItem.id);
    if (item < 0) { //it's a new item
        MovableItems.push(MovableItem);
    } else { //it's an existing item
        MovableItems[index] = MovableItem;
    }
}

function deleteMovableItem(MovableItem) {
    var index = getItem(MovableItems, MovableItem.id);
    if (index) {
        MovableItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. However, I can't get the XML to run. Apparently, there's error. By any chance, do you know of any other ways to help me? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, but if there's no other way that you know, can you please kindly tell me how to create an array which contains all the MovableItems(which contains all the information)? Perhaps, the reason for the error is the codes I use to create the array. Thanks and sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: Then I need to see more of your code. Can you at least show me how you created the single MovableItem?

Comment: Also, the error it stated when I'm passing the values to XML is "Cannot invoke size() on the array type String[]". I can't seem to figure out the problem though.

Comment: Sorry, it should be items.length (without brackets) not items.size(), I just corrected it

Comment: I also made several fixes to 'function deleteMovableItem(MovableItem)', please use the above updated one

Comment: Thanks. Now that there's no more error in that piece of code. I fave another problem. My XML page cannot be displayed. Its empty. Also, in the TomCat error, it states "Premature load of file". Please help :(

Comment: Did you add pw.println ( "<TemplateEditor>"); pw.flush(); 
pw.close(); br.close(); fw.close();... at the end of the JSP file. I omitted those lines when I posted the answer

Comment: Yes I did. However, it still post the same error. Is there something wrong with my XML codes?

Comment: Here's a explanation about a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708327/premature-end-of-file-error-when-java-read-and-writes-xml-data-files

Comment: Okay, now the XML file can show however, it does not display anything. Means the <X_Coord></X_Coords> does not have any values. Is the values not stored?

Comment: Can you print out the value of request.getParameter("movableItems");

Comment: Also, if you are using FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera or IE, you can open the debug tool (like Firebug...), and see what parameters/value are submitted to UpdateXML.jsp. One thing to check is whether movableItems parameter and its value is successfully passed to UpdateXML.jsp

Comment: No, I can't even print out the values. Apparently, it does not store the values.

Comment: OK. please try this: in the first jsp, add onsubmit="..." to the <form> element, like this: <form action="..." method="..." onsubmit="javascript:alert(document.getElementById('movableItems'));">, then reload the page. Then, when you submit the page, do you get any value in the alert box?

Comment: If you see null, empty value, or a value not in x.x.x.x|x.x.x.x format, it means the JavaScript in the first jsp is not implemented properly, otherwise the problem is probably in UpdateXML.jsp

Comment: It displays [Object] without any values. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it should be onsubmit="javascript:alert(document.getElementById('movableItems').value);"  (I missed the .value part)

Comment: Okay thanks! The values are displayed. However, it does not pass to the XML page.

Comment: Hi, now, I'm facing more problems than before. Is it okay if I send/email you the original codes and perhaps, you can help me out from there?

Comment: I would be glad to help you debug your code. The only thing is I don't know what the best way is to exchange email addresses here (I'm still very new to this site, as a registered user), if you know a good way, please let me know.

Comment: Oh, perhaps you just just tell me your email address here? Is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps Hotmail/Google email address or any others that you may have. This really means a lot to me. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi, I have emailed you. Did you receive it? My email address is ashiqindw@gmail.com . And thanks a lot, I really really mean it :)