# chrome.filesystem creating file and rename it

Tags: xml, google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have problem with some some printers, my chrome app create file(.xml) with content in folder and then printer prints it, but problem is that chrome first create empty file, then write content in it..

Like one of the answers in this question: ["Premature end of file" error when Java read and writes XML data files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708327/premature-end-of-file-error-when-java-read-and-writes-xml-data-files)

> Write your files to thename.xml.part and then once done/closed to a
>   rename to thename.xml, which makes the write closer to being atomic --
>   the reader can't read it until it's surely done so long as it is
>   looking for ".xml" files only.

How can i do that in chrome app?

This is my code so far:

```
    chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(printer_location, function(entry) {
        var uniqid = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)+Date.now()).toString();
        entry.getFile(uniqid+'.xml', {create:true}, function(entry) {
            entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.write(new Blob([xmlPrintText], {type: 'text/plain'}));
            });
        });
    });
```

this code create file, but i need to create with `.part` and then when done, to rename it without .part.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(print_location, function(entry) {
    var uniqid = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)+Date.now()).toString();
    var fileName = uniqid+'.xml';
    entry.getFile(fileName+'.part', {create:true}, function(entry) {
        entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.write(new Blob([xmlPrintText], {type: 'text/plain'}));
            writer.onwriteend = function(e) {
                rename(fileName+'.part', fileName);
            };
        });
    });
});
function rename(oldName, newName) {
    chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(printer_location, function(entry) {
        entry.getFile(oldName, {}, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.moveTo(entry, newName);
        });
    });
}
```